# Solving arbitrary long list of equations

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

Say I have equation for integer n = 1, 2, 3, ... N

```
eq[n_] := x[n] + n*x[n + 1] == 0
```

And say I wanna solve for N = 2 (so I have unknowns x[1], x[2], x[3] which set sum to 1)

```
 setofeqs = {eq[1], eq[2], x[1] + x[2] + x[3] == 1};
 Solve[setofeqs]
```

I can solve for N = 3 too (so I have unknowns x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4] which set sum to 1)

```
 setofeqs = {eq[1], eq[2], eq[3], x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] == 1};
 Solve[setofeqs]
```

How to code so setofeqs works for arbitrary number N?

Comment: Perhaps `RSolve` what you 're looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Globals`*"]
n = 3;
eq[n_] := x[n] + n*x[n + 1] == 0;

eqns = Append[Table[eq[i], {i, n}], Sum[x[i], {i, n + 1}] == 1]
Solve[eqns, Evaluate@Table[x[i], {i, n + 1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
RSolve[{x[n] + n*x[n + 1] == 0, Sum[x[i], {i, n + 1}] == 1}, x, n]
(*{{x -> Function[{n}, ((-1)^(1 + n)
  E Gamma[
  2 + n])/((-Gamma[1 + n] - n Gamma[1 + n] + Gamma[2 + n] + 
   Gamma[1 + n, -1] + n Gamma[1 + n, -1]) Pochhammer[
  1, -1 + n])]}}*)
```

Comment: If you take N+1 (my NN+1) as upper limit for the Sum in RSolve, you get the right result. `xsol[NN_] = 
 x /. First@
    RSolve[{x[n] + n*x[n + 1] == 0, Sum[x[i], {i, NN + 1}] == 1}, x, 
     n] // FullSimplify[#, NN > 1 && NN \[Element] Integers] & ; 
allx[NN_] := 
 Table[x[n] -> (xsol[NN][n]), {n, 1, NN + 1}] // FullSimplify; {allx[
  2], allx[3]} `